# MongoDB 4.2: Find by id and update another field (boolean) only if its falsy, and identify reason of an empty response

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to find a document by its `id` field and then update another field (`isLocked`) of that document only if that field has a value of false. I want to update only the `isLockedField`.

The MongoDB version is 4.2.

My first approach is to do 2 two queries:

1. Find the document by its id. If nothing is found, throw a `NotFoundError`.
2. Find and Update the document by doing a query `{ id: 'the-id', isLocked: false }`, and returning the new document. If this query returns an empty response, it means the document is Locked, then throw a `LockedError` (423).

Then I'd optimized that approach by doing both queries at the same time. After both promises resolve, throw the specific error if corresponds.

Is there another form that requires only one query to the db and being able to identify, if an empty response is returned, why is empty (not found by its id or because it is locked)?

Comment: what is your MongoDB version ?

Comment: Do you want to update only `isLocked` or also other fields?

Comment: @whoami I'm using mongo 4.2.

Comment: @TheeSritabtim I want to update only the `isLocked` field

Comment: @JCastilloSilva : *only if that field has a value of false* ? Do you mean if it has `true` don't you want to update the value (Why so) ? Also what all the values that `isLocked` can hold ?

Answer (score 1):

If you DO NOT want to update isLocked to true if e.g. it doesn't exist or is something completely different to `false`, you can use `findOneAndUpdate` and specify an aggregation pipeline as the update parameter.

```js
const result = db.collection('yourCollection').findOneAndUpdate(
    { id: 'this-id' },
    [{ $set: { isLocked: { $cond: { if: { $eq: ['$isLocked', false] }, then: true, else: '$isLocked' } } } }]
)

if (result.value === null) return NotFoundError
if (result.value.isLocked) return LockedError
```

The `value`-field of the result object contains the document before the update operation.

If it is OK to set `isLocked` to true when the field doesn't exist or contains any other datatype, then you can remove the condition and the `[]` around the `$set`, thereby specifying it as a normal update instead of an aggregation pipeline (tricky, i know):

```js
const result = db.collection('yourCollection').findOneAndUpdate(
    { id: 'this-id' },
    { $set: { isLocked: true } }
)
```

See: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.5/api/Collection.html#findOneAndUpdate

Comment: Nice! I think you can just `{ $set: { isLocked: true } }` instead of  `[{ $set: { isLocked: { $cond: { if: { $eq: ['$isLocked', false] }, then: true, else: '$isLocked' } } } }]` if we are sure that `isLocked` is boolean.

Comment: Yes, if you are sure that it is a boolean and if you want to update it to `true` even if the field does not exist in the document. But if that is the case you can also skip the array around the $set-field, since then you will not need the conditional logic provided by the aggregation-framework.

Comment: Updated the answer to handle both cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to modify `isLocked` field, you can use [`.updateOne()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-updateOne)

It returns the following:

```js
  res.n; // Number of documents matched
  res.nModified; // Number of documents modified
```

So basically you try to update `isLocked` to `true` no matter what the current value is.

Then you will be checking whether it has been modified or not.

Basically

```js
  const { n, nModified } = await Model.update({ id }, { $set: { isLocked: true } })
  if (n === 0) {
    throw new Error(‘NotFound’)
  }
  if (n > 0 && nModified === 0) { // or actually "if (nModified === 0)" because n should always be positive if it did not throw at the previous condition
    throw new Error(‘Locked’)
  }
```